# Open up multiple files in a folder in python for read/write

Tags: python, csv, file-io, python-3.x

So if I have a data folder that has, say 15 txt files within it, how can i open up multiple txt files at the same time witin that data folder in one function and another set within another?

So I wrote this:

```
with open("data/datafile.csv" , "r") as f :
    reader = csv.reader(f) 
    return list(reader)
```

So how can I do that same thing but with several files at the same time?

Comment: check out the `fileinput` module.

Answer (score 0):

If it is okay to not really do it all at *the same time*, all you could do is to put your reading into its own function (i.e. `read_csv`) then get all txt files in one directory and call your function for each file you find in the directory:

```
import os
def read_all_files(directory);
    return [read_csv(f) for f in os.listdir(directory) if f.endswith(".txt")]
```

This will call a function `read_csv` for each file that ends with ".txt" in the passed directory, and put it all into a big list which is returned.

Comment: Okay, but how would i open up one set of files in one function and another set in another? Say I have 15 files that are all txt and I need them in the same directory? Is there a way to specifically as for, say, files 1-5 in one function and 6-10 in another and 11-15 in another?

At the moment my only understanding of how this could be done is if there are certain pieces of information within the file that go up in scale. Like if my files all have lists of ascending data on ocean depth, I can set it so that I'm only looking at files up to a certain depth. (eg. if ocean_depth < 394.7)

Answer (score 0):

if it is important to have more files open at same time, then:

```
with open("data/datafile.csv" , "r") as f:
  with open("data/datafile2.csv" , "r") as f2:
    f.read()
    f2.read()
```

or

```
f = open("data/datafile.csv" , "r")
f2 = open("data/datafile2.csv" , "r")
f.read()
f2.read()
f.close()
f2.close()
```